# Change of data type after exporting from PostgreSQL to shapefile

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, postgresql

I had loaded shapefile created in QGIS 2.8.9 with following data type in PostgreSQL as shown in image.

[image: shape file fields]

After import the shapefile in PostgreSQL the data type shown as below.

[image: datatype in PostgreSQL]

When I export the data from PostgreSQL to shapefile its data type changes as shown below.

[image]

Is there any way to preserve the data type while exporting data to shapefile. I am using "PostGIS 2.0 Shapefile and DBF Loader Exporter" GUI.

Comment: Shapefile is an awful format for preseving data. This sort of unit creep is expected if you're not careful with the conversion. The only thing that would be worse would be going database-shapefile-database, since then you could lose several types completely, as well as numeric nulls wide strings and useful field names.

Comment: Datatypes in DBF is limited compared to PostgreSQL. See a similar discussion  but with ogr2ogr instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183598/ogr2ogr-from-pg-to-shp-changes-data-type-in-dbf

Comment: 2.8 is very old. I'd suggest updating to a recent version.